# Why did Zevulun complain?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, water, tractate-megillah, maseches-pesachim

The Gemara (Megillah 6a) tells us that Zevulun complained about having water in his portion instead of land, and Hashem consoled him with the Chilazon.

Question: In Pesachim 4a there is a story about someone who would always speak in praise of living by the water, and the sages discovered that the reason for that was because he came from Zevulun - so was Zevulun in favor of living by the water or not?

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer, but I have children, and 99% of the time I offer them a nice new thing, they complain that they don't like it when they first see it. After actually trying it, they end up praising it profusely!

Comment: Presumably by ca. 1500 years after the conquest of the land, the descendants of the tribe of Zevulun got used to their territory. And see [here](https://www.mayim.org.il/?meyuhadim=%D7%97%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95) many sources for "חן המקום על יושביו" (beauty of a place in the eyes of its dwellers).